# How to get and fit predictions from glmer?

Tags: r, lme4

I have tried a few suggestions on here and other sites but none seem to work

My model looks like

```
model = glmer(cbind(live, dead)~cont1*cont2+ (1|random),
                family = binomial, data = all)
```

cont1 and cont2 are both continuous explanatory variables, random is a random factor with about 8 levels

For a standard glm (i.e.)

```
model = glm(cbind(live, dead)~cont1*cont2, 
                   family = binomial, data = all)
```

I had used this code to get predictions

```
plot(-100,-100,xlim=c(0,30),ylim=c(0,100),xlab='cont1',
   ylab='alive(%)',col.axis='black',col.lab='black')
   preds = predict(model,data.frame(cont1=0:30,cont2=0),type='response')*100
   lines(0:30,preds,lty=5,lwd=3,col='magenta')   
   preds = predict(model,data.frame(cont1=0:30,cont2=-0.25),type='response')*100
   lines(0:30,preds,lty=3,lwd=3,col='purple')
```

etc.

I have been able to get predictions using glmer, but I cannot get predictions for each level of cont2 such as in the standard glm.

I have tried to copy the code suggested here [glmer - predict with binomial data (cbind count data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441817/glmer-predict-with-binomial-data-cbind-count-data)

```
predframe <- data.frame(cont1=(all$cont1), cont2=(all$cont2))
predframe$AlivePercent= predict(m1, newdata= predframe,type="response",REform=NULL)
```

However I get the error message

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 224
```

If anyone could suggest how I address this problem that would be hugely appreciated

Cheers,
Dylan

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: wild guess: do you want `REform=NA` rather than `REform=NULL`?